# Simplify Jacobi Polynomials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

How can I force Mathematica to use the identities satisfied by Jacobi polynomials
$$
(1-\cdot)P_n^{(\alpha+1,\beta)} = \frac{2}{2n+\alpha+\beta+2}\left((n+\alpha+1)P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}-(n+1)P_{n+1}^{(\alpha,\beta)}\right)
$$
$$
(1+\cdot)P_n^{(\alpha,\beta+1)} = \frac{2}{2n+\alpha+\beta+2}\left((n+\beta+1)P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}+(n+1)P_{n+1}^{(\alpha,\beta)}\right)
$$
to simplify expressions involving this polynomials in the sense that it is more preferable to have many Jacobi Polynomials multiplied by constants than a few multiplied by explicit monomials.

By using `FullSimplify` with `Assumptions` to tell Mathematica that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are greater than $-1$ I still obtain expressions containing products of Jacobi polynomials with $(1-t)$ or $(1+t)$

**Simple example**

When I input

```
FullSimplify[(1 - x) JacobiP[n, \[Alpha]+1, \[Beta], x], Assumptions ->   n \[Element] Integers && n > 0 && \[Alpha] > -1 && \[Beta] > -1 && x \[Element] Reals]
```

Mathematica just returns

```
-(-1 + x) JacobiP[n, \[Alpha]+1, \[Beta], x]
```

whereas I would like to get

```
2/(2 n + \[Alpha] + \[Beta] + 2) ((n + \[Alpha] + 1) JacobiP[n, \[Alpha], \[Beta], x] - (n + 1) JacobiP[n + 1, \[Alpha], \[Beta], x])
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a few simple examples of expressions that you believe should simplify by using this information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the desired example

Comment: It is not clear to me what "simpler" expression you are expecting for the example (i.e., a single Jacobi polynomial) and how it relates to the identities given.

Comment: `Mathematica` knows this identity, e.g. evaluating `FullSimplify[(1 - x) JacobiP[n, a+1, b, x]-2/(2n+a+b+2) ((n+a+1)JacobiP[n, a, b, x]-(n+1)JacobiP[n+1, a, b, x])]` yields `0`.

Comment: @BobHanlon I added more detail

Comment: @Artes I am aware that for Mathematica it's always simpler to simplify things when the expected output is zero, somehow I have to tell it to use this identity in this "other way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put an expression into a specific form, particularly if the desired form is not simpler in the normal sense (i.e., using the default complexity function), it may be easier using replacement rules along with [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The given identities are equivalent to these rules.

```
repl = {(1 - t_)*JacobiP[n_, α_, β_, t_] :> 
    2/(2 n + α + β + 1)*
     ((n + α)*JacobiP[n, α - 1, β, t] -
       (n + 1)*JacobiP[n + 1, α - 1, β, t]),
   (1 + t_)*JacobiP[n_, α_, β_, t_] :> 
    2/(2 n + α + β + 1)*
     ((n + β)*JacobiP[n, α, β - 1, t] +
       (n + 1)*JacobiP[n + 1, α, β - 1, t])};

expr1 = (1 - x) JacobiP[n, α, β, x];

expr2 = expr1 /. repl

(* (1/(1 + 2 n + α + β))2 ((n + α) JacobiP[
     n, -1 + α, β, x] - (1 + n) JacobiP[
     1 + n, -1 + α, β, x]) *)
```

Verifying,

```
expr1 == expr2 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Similarly,

```
expr3 = (1 + x) JacobiP[n, α, β, x];

expr4 = expr3 /. repl

(* (1/(1 + 2 n + α + β))2 ((n + β) JacobiP[
     n, α, -1 + β, x] + (1 + n) JacobiP[
     1 + n, α, -1 + β, x]) *)
```

Verifying,

```
expr3 == expr4 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and fast answer, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: In which order are the rules in 'repl' applied?

Comment: A rule is applied only if its LHS (pattern) matches a subexpression. In the examples given, only one rule applies. In more complex expressions they could both apply, they would then be applied sequentially in the order given. For more complex expressions you might also want to look at [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)